# How to save and load nn.Parameter() in pytorch, such that one can continue optimisation over it?

Tags: python, pytorch

I know how to store and load `nn.Model`, but can not find how to make a checkpoint for `nn.Parameter`. I tried this version, but the optimizer is not changing the `nn.Parameter` value after restoring.

```py
from torch import nn as nn
import torch
from torch.optim import Adam

alpha = torch.ones(10)
lr = 0.001
alpha = nn.Parameter(alpha)
print(alpha)
alpha_optimizer = Adam([alpha], lr=lr)

for i in range(10):
   alpha_loss = - alpha.mean()
   alpha_optimizer.zero_grad()
   alpha_loss.backward()
   alpha_optimizer.step()
   print(alpha)
path = "./test.pt"
state = dict(alpha_optimizer=alpha_optimizer.state_dict(),
               alpha=alpha)
torch.save(state, path)
checkpoint = torch.load(path)
alpha = checkpoint["alpha"]
alpha_optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint["alpha_optimizer"])
for i in range(10):
   alpha_loss = - alpha.mean()
   alpha_optimizer.zero_grad()
   alpha_loss.backward()
   alpha_optimizer.step()
   print(alpha)
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen?

Comment: I think this is still not a [mcve]. Could you also show how you try to optimize the variable after loading?

Comment: I made a proper minimal reproducible example.
I expected that last `alpha_optimizer.step()` will change values of `alpha`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the optimizer is still with a reference to the old `alpha` (check `id(alpha)` vs. `id(alpha_optimizer.param_groups[0]["params"][0])` before the last `for` loop), while a new one is set when you load it from the checkpoint in `alpha = checkpoint["alpha"]`.

You need to update the params of the optimizer before loading its state:

```py
# ....
torch.save(state, path)
checkpoint = torch.load(path)

# here's where the reference of alpha changes, and the source of the problem
alpha = checkpoint["alpha"]

# reset optim
alpha_optimizer = Adam([alpha], lr=lr)
alpha_optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint["alpha_optimizer"])

for i in range(10):
   alpha_loss = - alpha.mean()
   alpha_optimizer.zero_grad()
   alpha_loss.backward()
   alpha_optimizer.step()
   print(alpha)
```